# How to remove failed Test cases from allure report?

Tags: testing, architecture, allure

How to remove failed Test cases from allure report ?[please click here to check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7HgX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing more context I'm going to provide you an answer based on what I have (javascript, wdio and allure).

At the end of your test execution Allure generates some .xml files. Those .xml files are the ones that [Allure Commandline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline) uses to generate the HTML Report.

So what you need to do is:

Go to those .xml files and look for the test cases with the status=failed and remove them, after that you will need to generate the HTML reports again with the [Allure Commandline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline) and that's it, now those failed tests won't be displayed on the HTML report!

[image]